# Jquery:prepend() VS before() and append() VS after(), what's differences between them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Why the code below doesn't work, but It will work after I use `before()` and `after()` to replace prepend and append.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://libs.baidu.com/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn1").click(function(){
    $("img").prepend("<b>Before</b>");
  });

  $("#btn2").click(function(){
    $("img").append("<i>After</i>");
  });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<img src="/images/logo.png" >
<br><br>
<button id="btn1">Insert before</button>
<button id="btn2">Insert after</button>
</body>
</html>

Thanks,
Ethan
```

Answer (score 4):

The `<img />` is an empty tag, which means, nothing can be appended or prepended. So you need to either insert the new HTML before it or after it. That's why neither `append()` nor `prepend()` works, but `before()` works, because, it puts the content before `<img` tag and not inside it.

Better example with `div`:

```
<!-- Our Target -->
<div class="myDiv">Hello, World!</div>

<!-- Prepend("Hi: ") -->
<div class="myDiv">Hi: Hello, World!</div>

<!-- Append(" - Praveen ") -->
<div class="myDiv">Hello, World! - Praveen</div>

<!-- Before("Hi:) -->
Hi:
<div class="myDiv">Hello, World!</div>
```

Hope the above clarifies you about the three functions.

Comment: thanks a lot, Praveen.It's clear to me now.

Answer (score 0):

Because prepend tries to place it in the `<img>` tag before all the content, and `before()` places it before the `<img>` tag.

Comment: Exactly now, thanks L.